# Is it possible to remove all future notifications about an "important Windows update" you do not want to install?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I have an "important" Windows update that I do not want to install.

It keeps reminding me and there doesn't seem to be any way (in Windows 7) to remove it from the list of updates.

This is a problem because sometimes I do not notice new updates because I am so used to ignoring my "pending updates" notification in the status bar.

Anyone know how to remove this update so I am not asked about it again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are in the update centre right click on the offending update and click Hide Update. The update will no longer flag as needed.
This will allow windows to still notify you when updates are ready.

Answer (score -3):

Best of all, turn off all Windows Automatic Updates and do them manually.
I use www.askwoody.com to determine when to manually run the updates. When you do run updates, there are two buttons to choose from. Click the bottom button. Not the one that Microsoft recommends. You will be able to choose which updates you wish to install.